# How to show a "view attachment" button only if an attachment exists in the PDF form in adobe acrobat dc?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Im making a form using PDF form i Adobe acrobat DC. The form only consist of questions for the reporter to answer. The template will be filled out during a control of different work task. I created a "attach" button so that the reporter also can attach files to the pdf. How do I add a button so that the receiver know that there is an attach file to the pdf?

I know it easy to just press the icon on the left side but the receiver will forget that and the attached file would be really important not to miss.

Is there anyway to make a button shot that the receiver can press to show the attach file? the button can only show if there is a attached file and if not the button wont show.

Comment: Perhaps the `window.navigator` property would be useful here. [MDN window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator)

Comment: I dont know how to write codes? What javasqipt code should iput on the button so that it only shows when there is an ataached file to my pdf?